# What is the difference between 2 2x16 memory sticks and 4x16 memory sticks?

Tags: memory

What's the difference between buying the following:

- [G.SKILL TridentZ Series 32GB (2 x 16GB) 288-Pin DDR4 SDRAM DDR4 3200 (PC4 25600) Intel Z370 Platform Desktop Memory Model F4-3200C14D-32GTZSW](https://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?item=N82E16820232379) - $379.99
- [G.SKILL TridentZ Series 64GB (4 x 16GB) 288-Pin DDR4 SDRAM DDR4 3200 (PC4 25600) Intel Z370 Platform / Intel X99 Platform Desktop Memory Model F4-3200C14Q-64GTZSW](https://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?item=9SIA4YU4RM4605) - $1,018.46

To my naive eye, I do not understand why I don't buy two quantity of the top one and save (1,018.46)-(379.99*2)=258.48

What differences can there between two kits, when the kits have (a) the same manufacturer (b) the same marketing brand name (c) the same MT/s (d) the same timings (14-14-14-34) (e) the same MHz clock frequency tested by the manufacturer?

Is there a general principle I can follow when comparing two memory sticks from the same manufacturer?  My current framework is:

- Use ram.userbenchmark.com
- Make sure the RAM I am thinking about buying is compatible with my motherboard
- Look at timings - 14-14-14-34 seems to be the best for Z390 motherboards
- Look at MT/s and make sure I am comparing MT/s to MT/s and not MT/s to MHz.
- Read reviews - different manufacturers may be more likely to produce RAM that results in Blue Screen of Death (BSOD) and other annoying memory defects that may not be worth the hassle.

On top of this, I'm not really clear on why some memory is faster than others. For example, is it really better technology, or is it simply out-of-the-box one is configured to run faster than another?  For example, I see a lot of 1.35V RAM that seems to be faster than 1.2V RAM, but the 1.2V RAM has only slightly slower timings.  Wouldn't overclocking the 1.2V RAM with Intel XMP 2.0 Profiles allow me to lower the timings significantly, assuming my motherboard can handle it? (And what does it mean for a motherboard to "handle it", really?  Is this just as empirical as it sounds?)

Comment: Why did someone downvote this?  Can you please leave a comment and explain?

Comment: I don't know why the downvotes, but both links crash my current Firefox 63.0.3.

Comment: Without reviewing the links, buying two of the 2x16GB=32GB sets seems reasonable. From the specs I cannot see any disadvantage in doing so.

Comment: This would have been downvoted because it is a hardware shopping question, which is specifically off-topic on Superuser. Please read the Help article for [What can I ask about?](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: @MichaelFrank I don't see where it says hardware shopping is off-topic.  I do see product recommendations, but here, I am not asking for a recommendation in the traditional sense, I am asking to learn how to compare two different products.  Maybe the FAQ should be updated to clarify that, as I did read the FAQ prior to joining and it stinks as a new user to have a downvote upon joining the community.

Comment: Like... I consistently see 4x16GB more expensive than buying 2 2x16GB.  I have tried to find search terms online that can explain this, but I really don't know what the reasoning for it is.  I can see the model numbers are slightly different, but I don't know what the letter combinations mean.

Comment: @JohnZabroski  2 x 2x16 should work fine (its the specs of the DIMMS that make the difference, not the packaging).   Shopping recommendations aare explicitly off topic here, it does suck that this is not more clearly laid out in the signup though.

Comment: Rephrase the question to reduce the implied "Which one should I buy?" into something more like "What's the difference here?" and the question will probably squeak through.

Comment: The two kits contain identical modules, only the quantity, is the difference.

Comment: @MichaelFrank I've tried to reword the question, but I don't think I am an English major by any means.

Comment: @JohnZabroski You should take that last paragraph out and put it in another question. You already have an accepted answer for your original question, adding additional details is going to confuse future readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [G.Skill](https://gskill.com/en/) websites compare feature, there is no difference between these two sets of RAM (besides the number of sticks per package).

As far as model names go, I suspect `Q` stands for Quad Channel Kit, and `D` stands for Dual Channel Kit. The `32/64GTZSW` is the model number for that particular product.

[image: Comparison of 32GB kit vs 64GB kit]

So yes, you can safely buy whichever configuration of this RAM you find cheapest.

Answer (score 2):

For most users, there's no practical difference other than cost (though do make sure you compare cost properly, the difference in my experience is usually pretty small, often less than 2-3%).  Keep in mind that buying larger sets also makes returns more complicated (if one module is bad, you have to return the whole set).

There is one difference that may matter to power users though, as a general rule, all memory modules in a set use components from the same production batch, and are assembled together as part of the same production batch.  This has two practical implications:

- It's statistically slightly more likely to have multiple modules from a set packaged together fail at about the same time than it is to have the same number of individually bought modules fail at about the same time.  This usually isn't enough of a difference to matter to most people, but it can be important for people who need uptime guarantees.
- Because they were made together, they should all have the same production quirks, which means that they should be more likely to behave the same as each other when overclocked to an arbitrary degree, which in turn makes them easier to overclock safely.

The second point there is part of the reason for the difference in price, many dedicated DIY PC builders will often preferentially buy all the memory modules for their system as a single set even if it costs marginally more so that they know they will behave as closely as possible to each other.

Comment: Thank you.  This explains a lot, and not something I was able to find out about by googling and reading the usual hardware guides.

Comment: Thanks again.  Recently found another thread on another forum which mentions it is actually very hard to get 4 memory sticks to all work well together, despite being made by the same manufacturer and being the same model.  The user said that it is also very hard to return memory, and the restocking fee alone and repurchasing hassle might very well be worth the extra cost.